# Flutter Firebase phone Auth not catching errors

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I am using phone authentification with OTP codes with flutter.

My code:

```
checkPin(String pin) async {
    setState(() {
      checkingPin = true;
    });
    UserCredential? response;
    try {
      PhoneAuthCredential? credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
          verificationId: verificationCode, smsCode: pin);
      response = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (err) {
      print(err);
     
    } on FirebaseException catch (err) {
      print(err);
      
    } on PlatformException catch (err) {
      print(err);
     
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
     
    }
```

When purposely entering te wrong code, it throws a PlatformError. Despite me catching multiple errors (including PlatformError) in the ty catch block.

The error reads:

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(invalid-verification-code, The SMS verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid. Please resend the verification code SMS and be sure to use the verification code provided by the user., {code: invalid-verification-code, message: The SMS verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid. Please resend the verification code SMS and be sure to use the verification code provided by the user., nativeErrorMessage: The SMS verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid. Please resend the verification code SMS and be sure to use the verification code provided by the user., nativeErrorCode: 17044, additionalData: {}}, null))
```

I do not understand why it crashes the app rather than catching the error, when i explicity try to catch PlatformExceptions. My firebase_auth package version is :^3.3.5.

Comment: What is the stack trace for the error? Please share source code for PhoneAuthProvider too. Your code does not look the the documentation on https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone/

Comment: Sorry I couldn't look into your code. but [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone) might help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I did everything similar to what you did, but I found the reason for this in my case. It was throwing an exception because I was running it in `debug mode`. If you run it without `debug` mode, then it will not throw this exception.

In short, it is the Firebase function that is showing the exception in `debug` mode. If this doesn't work, then please let me know. I will try to look more into this.